# Round pandas dataframe numeric values in string type columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I did searched online posts but what I found were all how to only round float columns in a mixed dataframe, but my problem is how to round float values in a string type column.

Say my dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1111,2.2222, 'aaaa'], 'b':['bbbb', 2.2222,3.3333], 'c':[3.3333,'cccc', 4.4444]})
```

Looking for an output like

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1,2.2, 'aaaa'], 'b':['bbbb', 2.2,3.3], 'c':[3.3,'cccc', 4.4]})
```

----Above is a straight question------

----Reason why I do so is below----

I have 3 csv files, each has string header and float value, with different row and column number.

I need to append the 3 in one dataframe horizontally then expoert as a new csv, separate by a empty row.

My 3 dataframe like this:

---

One:

[image]

Two:

[image]

Three:

[image]

to

[image]

Pls note that the output dataframe contains headers from the 3 sub dataframe

So, when I import them, first csv of course imported by pd.read_csv, no issue.

Then I used .append(pd.Series([np.NaN])) to create an empty row as separator row

Then second csv loaded then I used pd.append(), but if I don't include 'header=None' in 'read_csv()' then the second one will not be mapped horizontally under first one, coz the csv files have uneven rows and columns.

So two options,

1. Include 'header=None' in 'read_csv()', then I can't simply use round() as

   df = df.round()

does not work, need to find a way to round only numeric values in each column

Also note that when include 'header=None', 
**All column types are 'object', by df.types**

2. Not include 'header=None' in 'read_csv()', then I could round each dataframe, but having trouble to combine them horizontally with their headers.

Any suggestion?

---

csv example

```
import pandas as pd
import io
exp = io.StringIO("""
month;abc;cba;fef;sefe;yjy;gtht
100;0.45384534;0.43455;0.56385;0.5353;0.523453;0.53553
200;0.453453;0.453453;0.645396;0.76786;0.36327;0.453659
""")

df = pd.read_csv(exp, sep=";", header=None)
print(df.dtypes)    
df = df.applymap(lambda x: round(x, 1) 
    if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else x)
print(df)
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way to loop over every single element in a dataframe using applymap. Combined with isinstance, which test for a specific type, you can get the following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1111,2.2222, 'aaaa'], 'b':['bbbb', 2.2222,3.3333], 'c':[3.3333,'cccc', 4.4444]})

df.dtypes

a    object
b    object
c    object
dtype: object

df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: round(x, 1) if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else x)
```

Obtaining the following dataframe:

```
      a     b     c
0   1.1  bbbb   3.3
1   2.2   2.2  cccc
2  aaaa   3.3   4.4
```

With the following dtypes unchanged

```
df2.dtypes

a    object
b    object
c    object
dtype: object
```

As for your other example in your question, I noticed that even the numbers are saved as strings. I noticed a method converting strings to floats `pd.to_numeric` for a `Series`.

From your `exp`, I get the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(exp, sep=";", header=None)
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'), axis=1)
df3 = df2.applymap(lambda x: round(x, 1) if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However it does not work. Just checked column types by (df.dtypes), they are all 'object'

Comment: It is strange as it worked for me even if columns dtypes were 'object'. applymap (not simply apply) is supposed to loop on the element, and recognize that a number is a float/int. Can you send back your code and resulting error message using my solution?

Comment: I found the difference, my dataframe was read from a csv, the csv file has string headers and float values. If I use pd.read_csv('input/service.txt', sep=";"), and your code, it works; if I use pd.read_csv('input/service.txt', sep=";", header=None), then it does not. df.dtypes from no 'header=None' are int64 and float64, and df.dtypes from 'header=None' are all object

Comment: I understand that your columns dtypes are object, but looking through the elements, python should recognize through isinstance if the element you are testing is a float/int. For example, if I set my df as:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1111,2.2222, 'aaaa'], 'b':['bbbb', 2.2222,3.3333], 'c':[3.3333,'cccc', 4.4444]})
I will get a df.dtypes of object for every columns. However, if I write the following:
type(df.iloc[0,0])
I get a float, proving that isintance should be able to work.

Comment: Can you try sending your txt file?

Comment: Hi Eric, I added an example in the post. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic! Works now! Thanks a lot!